# How to calculate the central moment giving function of a distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Is there a function which gives the central moments instead of just moments of a distribution and if so how to calculate this function for a distribution e.g. the normal distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moments, you may use the [characteristic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)):
$$\varphi_X(t) = \mathbb{E}[e^{itX}] \tag{1}$$
that gives
$$  \varphi_X^{(n)}(t) = \mathbb{E}[(iX)^n e^{itX}],\qquad \mathbb{E}[X^n] = i^{-n} \varphi_X^{(n)}(0).\tag{2} $$
The characteristic function of a normal $X=N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ variable is $e^{it\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t^2}$, hence in such a case:

$$ \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^n] = i^{-n}\frac{d^n}{dt^n}\left. e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 t^2}\right|_{t=0}\tag{3} $$
and since:
$$ e^{-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}t^2} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n \sigma^{2n}}{2^n n!}t^{2n}\tag{4} $$
it follows that:
$$ \mathbb{E}[(X-\mu)^{2m}]=\frac{\sigma^{2m}(2m)!}{2^m m!}.\tag{5}$$

Comment: Thank you for your response. Does that mean that there is no moment generating function which can be used for central moments?

Comment: @PKuhn: on the contrary, you just have to take the characteristic function of $X$ and multiply it by $e^{-\mu i t}$. That is the same as saying: just take $X-\mu$, that is a random variable with mean zero, and perform your computations with respect to that random variable.